# Do these functions (parabolas with opposite parity) ever occur in physics?

Tags: kinematics, mathematics, intuition, special-functions

Let's define

$$f_n(x)=(n-1)\operatorname{Li}_n\left(e^x\right)-x\operatorname{Li}_{n-1}\left(e^x\right)$$

(the function $\operatorname{Li}$ is [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm))

$$f_{even_n}(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2$$

$$f_{odd_n}(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2$$

At even $n$ the even part is polynomial, the odd part is its counterpart with opposite parity, a "pseudo-polynomial", at odd $n$ the even part is pseudo-polynomial, the odd part is polynomial.

The "pseudo-polynomials" have the same growth rate and asymptotically are approaching polyomials of the same order except having the opposite parity.

$f_{{even}_2}=\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{\pi^2}6$

-This is normal parabola.

$f_{{odd}_2}=\text{Li}_2\left(e^x\right)+ x \log \left(1-e^x\right)-\left(\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}\right)$

-This is an odd "parabola".

[image]

$f_{even_3}=2 \text{Li}_3\left(e^x\right)-x \text{Li}_2\left(e^x\right)-\left(\frac{x^3}{12}+\frac{\pi ^2 x}{6}\right)$

-This is even "cubic parabola".

$f_{odd_3}=\frac{x^3}{12}+\frac{\pi ^2 x}{6}$

-This is normal cubic function.

[image]

Do such functions appear in nature or physics? Do objects in some fields move along trajectories defined by these curves?

Comment: You can make any particle travel along a 1-D trajectory $x(t)$ by postulating a force law $F(t) = m \ddot{x}(t)$ (along with the appropriate initial conditions.)  And if you can invert the function $t(x)$, you can in principle get a position-dependent force $F(x) = m \ddot{x}(t(x))$.  So to ask whether a force law exists that produces a particular trajectory isn't particularly meaningful;  you can do it for pretty much any function locally.